# Can't connect to network drives after restart in any way

Tags: windows, network-shares

This is the situation: 
New Workstation with Windows 10. 
Connected to the network via ethernet.
Network drive adress: \\example.company.com\folder\subfolder\subfolder\accessablefolder
  The network group is WORKGROUP. The PC is not in a domain. Network is set to private. Internet connection is stable.

So when I create a new account I can add this drive and connect it okay. But if I restart the computer and login to the local account the drive is still present but when I try to connect it fails. It actually takes a long time to fail and the explorer seems to nearly crash. This only happens for user accounts (with or without admin rights). The predefined Windows Administrator account works just fine. There is no space in the account name. It does not matter if you try to connect via the wizard or via cmd net use (....) There seems to be no difference in any configuration between the admin account and the user account.

On all other machines it works well (except for you have to double click the drive if you want to use it after restart but that seems to be a MS bug and is not critical for us)

So far I've tried everything. And the problem still persists. I hope you can help me.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Thank you

PS: I'm not in charge for adminstration of the network drives

Edit:
The Problem has been solved. For whatever reason the checkbox for logging in with a different account had to be enabled. Even if you enter the correct credentials at first. Don't ask me why. I don't completely understanding it myself.

Comment: Windows has a problem where shares created by admin could only work for admins, and vice versa. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @harrymc How long has this been a thing? Most shares in our environment were created by admins but no one has had issues trying to connect to them yet. Is it just a bug, and we got lucky?

Comment: It's a very old thing that stayed for a very long time without known precise rules. I haven't checked if anything changed lately, but as in your case the share works for the Administrator, this reminded me of it.

Comment: @harrymc the drives are connected within the user account. I tried to connect it via the Admin account but it wasn't able to cause of some minor issues. I have access to the user account so I did not held myself with bothering with that.